# Load spring config programmatically

Tags: java, spring, microservices

I have 3 micro services which all need use a 'common' library. I need to add a new Spring configuration to the common library. The problem is that Microservice A doesn't care about the new code and doesn't want to be forced to add config in order to get the application to run. I need a way of programmatically loading the config only for Microservice B and C.

New config in common library:

```
@Configuration
public class HttpConnectionConfiguration {

    @Value("${http.connect.timeout}")
    private int httpConnectTimeout;

    @Value("${http.connect.request.timeout}")
    private int httpConnectRequestTimeout;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(getClientHttpRequestFactory());

        return restTemplate;
    }

    private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(httpConnectTimeout)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(httpConnectRequestTimeout)
                .build();

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
                .create()
                .useSystemProperties()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .build();

        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
    }
}
```

Config in Microservice B and C of application.yaml:

```
http:
  connect:
    timeout: 5000
    request:
      timeout: 5000
```

Microservice B and C start fine, but A gives this error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'http.connect.timeout' in value "${http.connect.timeout}`

What is the best way around this problem without providing dummy values in microservice A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** use a configuration hierarchy with an additional `@Configuration` class that makes a `RestTemplate` bean, and activate it only for B and C (or when the property is available):

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("http.connect.timeout")
public class HttpConnectionConfiguration {

    // rest of code ...
```

**Solution 2:** use defaults. Since the [default timeout is `-1`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html#getConnectTimeout()), use that:

```
    @Value("${http.connect.timeout:-1}")
    private int httpConnectTimeout;

    @Value("${http.connect.request.timeout:-1}")
    private int httpConnectRequestTimeout;
```

Comment: couple of questions regarding solution 1: how do you add multiple ConditionalOnProperty as there are a few properties i should probably include. Also,  after including that suggested annotation it now throws: ` Bean method 'restTemplate' in 'HttpConnectionConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (http.connect.timeout) did not find property 'http.connect.timeout'`

Comment: Obviously you shouldn't autowire or otherwise access a RestTemplate bean in the A configuration. You can achieve that by not instantiating B and C in the A configuration (do more fine-grained component scanning, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify default values inside `@Value` using SpEL Expression like below.

```
@Value("${http.connect.timeout:10}")
private int httpConnectTimeout;

@Value("${http.connect.request.timeout:10}")
private int httpConnectRequestTimeout;
```